# How many frames can human eye see?

Tags: biophysics, biology, vision, perception

- What's the limitation of our eyes?
- Can we differentiate 60fps from 120fps?
- Are new 144hz monitors just a marketing trick?

*Couldn't find any proper journals or studies about the matter.*

Comment: Like the question, I am wondering if the eye is the limiting step tho, because consciousness has been measured at 40-90 frames per second per one source I read. Will follow what we hear from the community on this.

Comment: Some interesting discussions [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=318137)

Comment: "Are new 144hz monitors just a marketing trick?" Yes, just like the absurd numbers of pixels you see today, far smaller than the angular resolution of most people's poor eyesight.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - you are right about numbers of pixels. Last year I was in the market for a new Mac, and went to see the 5k display. I was wowed. Then I noticed I was looking at the 2.5k display... they had been moved around in the shop, and even the Mac "genius" hadn't noticed. So I saved $700 on the display and upgraded my processor, memory, disk drive instead. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human perception, not physics.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/limit-of-human-eye-flicker-perception

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88892/26969

Comment: There is a good reason 24 Hz was good enough for the early motion-picture industry. Human eyes have not evolved significantly since then, so 144 Hz is overkill for watching the latest episode of the Simpsons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Different parts of the eye have different response speed. The corner of your eye doesn't see color, but is fast; the center sees color, and is slower. This means that when you look at a 60 Hz monitor straight-on, the image is perfectly steady; but when you look at it from the corner of your eye, it is flickering. As you go to even higher frequencies of refresh, even the rods don't respond fast enough.

This make sense from an evolutionary perspective. When the saber-toothed tiger jumps at you, you need to know about it - quickly. You don't need to know its color. So using the faster rods (sensitive, fast, no color sense) in the edge of the field of view is a good survival strategy. But since we can't move very far in 1/100th of a second, there is no need for sensors that respond at that speed.

The difference is real, and can be perceived. In the corner of your eye, for most people.

Incidentally, the rendering of fast motion is helped by the higher frame rate; if you show a bright object against a dark background moving left-to-right across the screen in 1/30th of a second, the brain will notice the difference between "two images comprise the full motion" and "four images comprise the full motion", even if you don't really perceive the individual frames. You will see a smoother action when more frames make up the motion: after all, in real life you really see "infinitely many frames" even though they blur together.

Answer (score 2):

The conscious part of the human brain cannot process visual information that persists for less than about .04 seconds while the subconscious part is thought to be faster. What the brain is doing is pattern recognition in either case (which requires a considerable amount of mental processing).  The issue is how long does this mental processing require and the implication is that the subconscious is faster than the conscious.

In the field of intelligence there is an hypothesis (based upon the above) called the 25th frame effect. If true it would enable someone to transmit subliminal information via a 25 fps video that incorporates an out of context frame at every 25th position. The subject would not be conscious of this attempted manipulation.

There was a rumor during the 1950s that movie theaters were subliminally encouraging customers to purchase food and drink items by inserting 25th frame images (of coke or popcorn, for example) just before the intermission. Congress passed a law against such subliminal manipulation as a result of this rumor.

During a presidential campaign in the US a number of years ago an add was aired in support of a republican candidate that included the word "Democrats" in the message. Some people noticed a flicker in the film while this word appeared and it was discovered that one frame of the add had dropped the first five letters of the word leaving "rats."  The republicans vowed that this was not an illegal 25th frame attack against their opponent (attempting to form a subliminal association between Democrats and rats in the minds of voters) and no legal action was taken.

Comment: The eye does not transmit information to the brain in frames. An alka-seltzer tablet at the bottom of a glass of water does not transmit bubbles to the surface in frames. So FPS is not a measurement that applies to the human visual perception system itself.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, I am a bit skeptical of your assertion, just because the receiving cells have to refresh in a biological way(more a chemical way).  But I am open to your argument,

Comment: @Ed: See 1) [Does perception have a frame rate](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/does-perception-have-a-frame-rate), 2) [Can the human eye distinguish frame rates above 60 Hz?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/can-the-human-eye-distinguish-frame-rates-above-60-hz), 3) [What is the equivalent of shutter-speed in Human eye?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/what-is-the-equivalent-of-shutter-speed-in-human-eye), 4) [Limit of human eye flicker perception?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/limit-of-human-eye-flicker-perception) etc.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick tho your argument is highly supported if the rods and cones have different recruitment times.  I will have to check that out.

Comment: I should also mention [Is mammalian vision processed as a sequence of frames?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-mammalian-vision-processed-as-a-sequence-of-frames)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick.  Thank you for the reference. Will do!!!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I'm not saying that the eye transmits information to the brain in frames.  What I'm saying is that if information is presented in discrete frames, the conscious brain loses the ability to distinguish between that and a continuous flow of information at about 25 fps, while the subconscious has a higher frame rate capacity.  What the brain is doing is pattern recognition which requires a considerable amount of mental processing.  The question is how long does this mental processing require and the implication is that the subconscious is faster than the conscious.

Comment: @Lewis maybe you could edit *"the human eye does not transmit visual information to the conscious part of the brain at greater than 25 fps"* to make it clear by removing the implication it can transmit n frames a second where n < 26. E.g. something like "The visual system cannot consciously distinguish changes that take place in less than 0.04 seconds"

Comment: $RedGrittyBrick I have followed your suggested edit. Shall we delete the comments? Maybe not since others joined in.